# Laravel query orderBy pivot table value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have a trouble that I can't resolve.

I have two models **User** & **Orgs**
They are bounded by a pivot table **user_org** through a belongsToMany relationship.
An user can be member of many Orgs and an Orgs can have many users.

Into my controller I craft a query :
`$users = User::query();`

I wanted to get $users depending on various filters, no problem to apply filters, then order them by orgs if they have one "VIP" orgs through some weighting with `orderByRaw("CASE WHEN org_id = X THEN 1 ELSE 2 END")`

[EDIT] Full query over here :

```
$users = User::query();
$queryOrder = "CASE WHEN org_id = 13 THEN 1 "; 
$queryOrder .= "WHEN org_id = 14 THEN 2 "; 
$queryOrder .= "ELSE 3 END"; 

$users = $users->join('user_org', 'user_org.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->orderByRaw($queryOrder);
```

Adding distinct() didn't do the job.

Problem, the result of the query give me some duplicate as an user can belongs to severals orgs.
I can't manage to sort the users giving me firstly the users who belongs to the VIP orgs.

Did you have any clue for me ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've managed by problem differently.
Because the distinct is not working due to the inner join, the order are lost in the better case.

So I've made a "score" computed column in order to group by user_id and max(score).

Here is the request :

```
            $users = $users->join(
                    DB::raw("(select id, score from (
                                select user_id as id, MAX(CASE WHEN org_id = 13 THEN 5 WHEN org_id = 14 THEN 4 ELSE 0 END) as score 
                                FROM `user_org`
                                group by user_id
                                order by score DESC
                                ) as x)
                            as d"), function($join){
                    $join->on("d.id","=","users.id");
            });
```

Thanks for the answer and the help !
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a [distinct clause](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects)?

```
$users = User::query(...)->distinct()->get();
```

Just FYI, this question reminds me [a recent Laracon talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBUXXErAtuk). He used 'orderBySub'. This could be an alternative for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help but this is not working for my case :(
`$queryOrder = "CASE WHEN org_id = 13 THEN 1 ";
        $queryOrder .= "WHEN org_id = 14 THEN 2 ";
        $queryOrder .= "ELSE 3 END";
        $users = $users->join('user_org', 'user_org.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->distinct()->orderByRaw($queryOrder);`
Still have duplicate.

Comment: I have updated the question with the full query @Kevin